# How can a defrecord's format be inferred from data described as defrecords?

Tags: clojure, xml-parsing

Documentation for data.xml/parse says

*The data is returned as defrecords and can be manipulated using the normal clojure data structure functions*.

Can the structure of those defrecords be inferred manually or programmatically, and, if so, how?

Here is the example in the docs compacted somewhat:

```
(let [input-xml (java.io.StringReader. 
                 "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
                 <foo><bar><baz>The baz value</baz></bar></foo>")]
  (parse input-xml))

#clojure.data.xml.Element{:tag :foo,
                      :attrs {},
                      :content 
(
#clojure.data.xml.Element{:tag :bar, 

:attrs {},
:content (#clojure.data.xml.Element{:tag :baz,
         :attrs {},
         :content ("The baz value")})})}
```

Comment: The structure of the defrecords corresponds to the structure of the XML tree itself, not your schema. Think of it as a Clojure-ized version of the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, defrecords can be operated on as maps, because that is essentially what they are.

For example:

```
problems.core=> (defrecord Dog [name collarsize])
```

Now, we have defined a defrecord type, a Dog.

```
problems.core=> (keys (Dog. "laly" 1))           
(:name :collarsize)
```

So clearly, the "keys" function, which we all know and love for operating on maps, works fine.

But to take it further, we find that a defrecord, alas, is truly a map :

```
problems.core=> (map? (Dog. "laly" 1))           
true
```

So -- why all this fuss over a simple map ?  Because, since xml has a well-defined structure, it makes sense that we can have some gauranteed keys in every defrecord returned.  In particular, the defrecord elements ill each have ":tag, :attrs, and :content".  To confirm, you can note thatthese constant defrecord attributes are always present in the online tutorials of parsing xml with clojure (i.e. http://www.gettingclojure.com/cookbook:xml-html ).